# Example Use SOAP Web Service in Flutter

Tags: api, web-services, flutter, soap, wsdl

i want to know how use a web Service wsdl Soap in flutter .. I want  to use the function getPersonneByFace . In the Api they define the function like 




in the Soap web Service ... 
What can i put in the header and how use the result ..

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  If you show us what you've attempted so far, we'll be in a better position to assist you.

Comment: this the request on Postman     <Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <getAllAppareil xmlns="http://afiswebservice.sacs.ci/"/>
    </Body>
</Envelope>

Comment: Would you mind editing your original post and including it there?